# Just started out learning to code and it won't execute

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So i am watching youtube tutroials and trying to write hello world but i am already failing

Here is an screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha77I.png)

Why won't it execute?

Any help would be really welcome (From Belgium so excuse my broken english)

Comment: Avoid uploading source code and cmdline output as images. Try an explicit output location for the binary (`-o`) i.e `g++ youtube.cpp -o youtube && ./youtube`

Comment: Visual Studio Code can't find the compiled binary since it's by default searching for "a.out" with no path specifiied. Check where g++ is compiling your binary and the name of the binary.

Comment: Youtube is no substitute for [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), especially when dealing with a complicated language like C++. Remember that youtube is not an expert-curated site, so bat-smurf crazies are able to post tutorials just like anyone else. Pick and choose your tutorials carefully. A good background in the fundamentals of C++ will help you pick more sucessfully.

Comment: Actually, @Yuumi, he specified "./a.out", which absolutely does include the path.

Comment: Additional handy reading: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). You can get more information by taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: My advice is to try this Microsoft tutorial before you continue: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: I tried to debug your program, but my IDE doesn't know how to extract code from an image.   No code posted as text == no help.

Comment: i have some books about coding, yet i find videos more pleasing for me to learn from videos.

I use more then one source of teacher on the internet

Comment: anyway ill check out the information u all posted, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on Windows.  Instead of `a.out`, the default name for gcc is `a.exe`.  You can see that in the directory listing on the left.

Comment: HAVING SAID THAT, the other replies are right.  I NEVER let `g++` use the default name.  I ALWAYS specify `g++ -o xxx.exe  xxx.cpp` so that I control the name.